# Cygwin Bash doesn't inherit all CMD's environment variables

Tags: cygwin, environment-variables

If I enter `echo %AppData%` in a `CMD` window, I get `C:\Users\User.Name\AppData\Roaming`.  If I enter `echo $AppData` in a Cygwin Bash shell, I get nothing.  However, most environment variables in CMD *do* get inheritted by a Cygwin  Bash shell.  What can I do to ensure that all environment variables propagate from `CMD` to a Cygwin Bash shell?

Comment: As bash is case-sensitive, so are probably the variable names. Use `env` to check if that's the problem.

Comment: @harrymc: That's it!  Thanks!  Did you want to post that as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As bash is case-sensitive, so are probably the variable names.

Use `env` to check if that's the problem.